# Is the querylist in the asyncSession working?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, greendao

i am currently stuck in a problem with the asyncSession. I tried to not just make a list, i wanted to call asyncSession.queryList(). 
I don't have the log-file rightnow, but it basically said that the query wasn't build in the currentThreat. (I am building it one line above)
So i tried to add .forCurrentThread(), but i got the same error.

Is this feature basically working?
Otherwise i will bring some more information tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and came to the conclusion this was a bug. I ended up changing the method `executeOperation()` in AsyncOperationExecutor.java:

```
case QueryList:
            operation.result = ((Query) operation.parameter).forCurrentThread().list();
            break;
case QueryUnique:
            operation.result = ((Query) operation.parameter).forCurrentThread().unique();
            break;
```

Adding in the call to `forCurrentThread()` changes the owning thread of the Query to the thread of the ExecutorService. This made it work for me, I wonder if there is a better solution though.